# Count of all colums which are not null

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

A query to fetch the count of all columns which are not null;

```
id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
--------------------------------
1  | abc  | ---  |  xyz | pqr  |
--------------------------------
2  | def  |  ghi |  --- | pqr  |
--------------------------------
3  | ---  |  --- | hgy  | ---  |
--------------------------------
4  | ---  | jko  |      | uyi  |
--------------------------------
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 1 WHERE Col1!='---'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 1 WHERE Col2!='---'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 1 WHERE Col3!='---'
```

In a single query

How to get the result as

```
-----------------------
Cnt1| Cnt2 |Cnt3| Cnt4|
-----------------------
2   |  2   | 2  |  3  |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

Funnily enough:

```
select count(col1) cnt1, count(col2) cnt2, count(col3) cnt3, count(col4) cnt4
from table1
```

Comment: Can You Please check the question clearly
I Dont need the count of columns.
I Need the count of columns which are not null in where condition (null is represented as ---)

Comment: @NaveenKumar Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count): "Returns a count of the number of **non-NULL** values of expr in the rows ..."

Comment: The query gave the result as 4 4 4 4

Comment: @NaveenKumar: Are those columns NULL (as stated in the question), or do they have a specific value (such as an empty string, or `'---'` as shown in the sample data) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with data as (
  select * 
  from ( values
      (null, null, null, null),
      (   1, null, null, null),
      (   2,    4, null, null),
      (   0,    5,    6, null)
  ) data(col1,col2,col3,col4)
) 
select 
  sum(case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end),
  sum(case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end),
  sum(case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end),  
  sum(case when col4 is null then 0 else 1 end)
from data
```

which nicely yields:

```
 ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------  
          3           2           1           0
```

Comment: select 
  sum(case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end),
  sum(case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end),
  sum(case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end),  
  sum(case when col4 is null then 0 else 1 end)
from data
worked perfectly fro my requirement..Thank You

Comment: Yes; the rest is constructing sample data to test with.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:mysql], which does not support the `WITH` syntax.

Comment: @eggyal: The `with syntax is just to create test data. !!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have '---' values instead of nulls. In this case:

```
select count(nullif(col1,'---')) as cnt1, count(nullif(col2,'---')) as cnt2, count(nullif(col1,'---')) as cnt3, count(nullif(col1,'---')) as cnt4 from table1;
```